# How can i count all the elements of this whole php array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
   $players = array(
                        array('Lionel Messi', 'Luis Suarez', 'Neymar Jr'),
                        array('Ivan Rakitic', 'Andres Iniesta', 'Sergio Busquets'),
                        array('Gerrard Pique', 'Mascherano', 'Denis Suarez', 'Jordi Alba'),
                        array('MATS'),
                        array('Arda Turan', 'Munir El Hadadi', 'Umtiti')
                        );
```

Now i am trying to echo the number of all the elements within the boundary of this array $players. For example, there are 3 elements in the first, 3 in the second. There are 4 elements in the third, 1 element in the 4th and 3 elements in the last one. Altogether these elements are 14 elements. Now i want to display 'Total Players: 14'. I can show the number of categories (5) using count() function but can't count the total elements(14). I tried different approaches but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native `count()` method can do that.

```
$count = count($players, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($players);
```

Because the recursive `count` will also count the number of `$player` groups you have, you have to subtract that number from the recursive count.

From the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) for `count`:

> If the optional mode parameter is set to COUNT_RECURSIVE (or 1), count() will recursively count the array. This is particularly useful for counting all the elements of a multidimensional array.

Comment: i appreciate your answer. But i have got another problem here.

Comment: I have categorized each array  with a specific category name as Category 1, Category 2, Category 3, Category 4 and Category 5. Now it is COUNT_RECURSIVE is counting these 5 categories too. Giving a result of 19 instead of 14.

Comment: You could `count` the number of categories and subtract that number from the `19`. Or, instead of using a recursive count, you could `foreach` through your actual players (not categories) and get the sum of each player count. Up to you.

Comment: $playerCount = count($players, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($players); this is the perfect code. it worked out for me. it is giving the exact answer. But thanks for your time too. I appreciate!

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested. I updated my answer to reflect that. Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 3):

[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) should be able to do this for you directly, using the `COUNT_RECURSIVE` flag:

```
$playerCount = count($players, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($players);
// $playerCount is now equal to 14
```

The subtraction of the normal count is because counting recursively adds the keys of the outer array in to the sum of elements, which just needs to be subtracted from the recursive count.

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek np, glad to help.

Comment: that '-count($players)' is the actual stuff! I needed that. You rock. Thanks once again!

Comment: i was having the rest code but that used to count the whole stuff including the names of the categories and the result used to be 19, but now its perfect!

Comment: @JeffLambert +1 for mentioning `COUNT_RECURSIVE`. Completely forgot about this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One other way, pretty self-explanatory:

```
$count = array_sum(array_map('count', $players));
```

Comment: $playerCount = count($players, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($players); This is the working code! It works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, that certainly does work. But as with many things, there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: exactly. but i appreciate your recommendation too.. may be this would work out too . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable initialised to 0 to accumulate the number of elements. Then, iterate the first array (which contains the other arrays), and for each element (which is also an array) use `count()` to obtain the number of elements and add that value to the accumulator variable.

```
$num_players = 0;

foreach($players as $row) {
  $num_players += count($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$count=0;
foreach($players as $row) $count+=count($row);
```

`$count` is now 14.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/GHZ6A)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use:

```
count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

[check count manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)