Why does count() with COUNT_RECURSIVE returns incorrect result for my 2-d array?
I have filled a 2 dimensional array with the following code
    $chessboard = array(
    array('r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'),
    array('p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'),
    array(' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
    array(' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
    array(' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
    array(' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
    array('P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'),
    array('R','N','B','Q','K','B','N','R'));

When I count 1 row it returns 8 items as expected (see the output a bit further below):
echo "count: " . count($chessboard) . "<br />";

But when I count both dimensions then the answer is that there are 72 items?
(see the output a bit further below)
echo "count all: " . count($chessboard, COUNT_RECURSIVE) . "<br />";

Somehow there seems to be an extra row or column?
I suspect an extra row but I see no extra row when I display the whole chessboard array:
  echo "<pre>the board:<br />";
  foreach ($chessboard as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $piece){
      echo "-$piece-";
    }
    echo "<br />";
  }
  echo "the end</pre>";

This displays:

I added the extra '-' to show the spaces better while testing this issue.
I would have expected a total count of 64 (8x8) ... why is it showing 72? where does the extra row (or column) come from?
How could I change it so that the array is still filled correctly, but the count shows 64 correctly?

The array contains 8 subarrays and each contains 8 elements, so there are totally 8 + 8 x 8 elements.

Look at this example in the manual: subarrays themselves count for 1.

@shingo : ah thanks!!! that explains why i dont see anything else in the output .. quite logical as well to be honest ... thanks! If you post it as an answer then i can mark it as the solution :-)

This question doesn't need an answer, as it's based on a confusion

@YourCommonSense : it might help other people who are as confused as me :-)

Not likely with its current title. Which is a confusion in itself

You could also have given a much simpler test case. count([[1]], COUNT_RECURSIVE) returns 2, it was enough.

@Olivier I cannot find a reliable dupe so it seems that an answer is rather justified.

In my opinion, PHP should add an option like COUNT_RECURSIVE_WITHOUT_ARRAYS or something, because the result is indeed counterintuitive.

Ah, found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236798/how-can-i-count-all-the-elements-of-this-whole-php-array, on the second Google page

Oh, and with proper request, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062770/multi-dimensional-array-count-in-php
